# Get html from jQuery dynamically created object

Tags: jquery

```
var toCartButton = $('<input/>', {
            type: 'button',
            value: "В корзину!",
            href: '#',
            class: "btn btn-success"
        });
```

> toCartButton.html()
>
> ""

Comment: what is error ? give more html and script please

Comment: What problem you have?

Comment: `toCartButton .val()`

Comment: `input` tags don't have `html`. Use `val()`

Comment: toCartButton.html() gives ""

Comment: $(toCartButton).html() also gives ""

Comment: @Tushar I want html not val

Comment: [<input type=​"button" value=​"В корзину!" href=​"#" class=​"btn btn-success">​]

Comment: Just do it directly -> `$('<input type="button" value="В корзину!" href=  '#' class= "btn btn-success" ');` and button will not have `href` attribute!!

Comment: use **toCartButton[0].outerHTML**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `outerHTML` to get Html string

```
toCartButton[0].outerHTML
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdL8jgbt/2/)**

Comment: It is just created. It is not yet thrown in `DOM`

Comment: @Tushar The code works.